# java heap error in flash builder 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, sdk, flash-builder

I m currently using adobe flash builder 4.6 n there is java heap space error. i cleaned my project every time but it's not working is there any permanent solution for this issue, plz help as soon as possible.

Comment: What is giving you a Java Heap Space error?  Running your Flex Application?  Compiling your Flex Application?  Something else in the IDE?  Can you post the full error text you see?  What type of project did you create?  Which version of the Flex SDK are you using?  Have you tweaked the eclipse memory settings?

Comment: I am using flex sdk 4.6, i working on mvc framework based desktop application n  there is compile time java heep error, n i did the temporary solution by increase FlashBuilder.ini parameters .is there any other parmanent solution. n now my sdk sometimes shows undefined error.????? is there any idea abt that ?

Answer (score 6):

**java heap error** comes for several reason like a build a project which has too much library in it build path for this type of project you have to build individual library and then build main Project.

You can increase a heap memory flash builder 4.6(FB 4.6) manually. 1024MB is a maximum limit of heap memory allocation. you can't allocate more memory than 1024MB.
go to `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6` and open **FlashBuilder.ini** file and update the line **-Xmx512m** to **-Xmx1024m**. By default 512MB heap memory allocate to heap. but you can increase it manually.

**warning**

if you try to increase heap memory more than 1024 then your FB 4.6 not open.

if this not solves your problem then put a log file 
[image]

Comment: I'll add that Flash Builder 4.7 has a 64-bit version which should allow more allocated memory.

Comment: agree to Mr.www.Flextras.com, you can use FB 4.7 which support JAVA 1.7 and more heap memory. May this will help you...

Comment: Or switch to an IDE that works. I've heard that FB 4.7 is even worse than its predecessor stability-wise. These are your alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918992/is-flash-builder-for-flex-also-open-source/13919211#13919211